# iOS: Navigation toolbar is not appearing with SplitViewController

Tags: ios, swift, ios8

I am using a splitViewController which has a master and two different detail view controllers.
When the app loads, first detail view controller loads with navigation toolbar. But if I go back to master view controller and open same detailed view controller, Navigation toolbar disappears.

Tried to change detailViewController as follows but it does not work:

```
override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)
        if !appDelegate.loggedIn {
            self.performSegueWithIdentifier("loginScreen", sender: self)
        }
        self.navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(false, animated: false)
    }

    override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
        navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(false, animated: false)
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(false, animated: true)

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to embed both your detail view controllers in Navigation controller. You can do this by selecting view controller in the storyboard.

Hit EDITOR Menu Tab.

Navigate to EMBED IN

And select Navigation Controller.